# Can a single field from a List<struct> be searched using IndexOf?

Tags: c#, list, struct, indexof

In C#, I have a List where someStruct consists of a String and an int.  I want to be able to find the entry matching a particular String.  Is there something along the lines of IndexOf() that can do it, or do I have to use a *for* loop and check each entry's string field for a match?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query),

```
var yourItem = list.FirstOrDefault(entry=>entry.SomeProperty=="SomeValue"); // or list.First
```

You can also use the `Find` method of List:

```
var yourItem = list.Find(entry=>entry.SomeProperty=="SomeValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via the [FindIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `List<T>`:

```
var list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(new Item { Id = 1, Data = "Test1" });
list.Add(new Item { Id = 2, Data = "Test2" });
var index = list.FindIndex(x => x.Id == 2); // Second scenario FindIndex(x=> x.Data == "Test2");
```

Where `Item` is:

```
public struct Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to use an index if you are looking up the string and returning the id:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Item> myList = new List<Item>() {
                                  new Item()  {Id = 123, Data = "abc"},
                                  new Item()  {Id = 124, Data = "abd"},
                                  new Item()  {Id = 125, Data = "abe"},
                                  new Item()  {Id = 126, Data = "abf"},
                                  new Item()  {Id = 127, Data = "abg"}
            };

            int id = myList.Where(x => x.Data == "abe").Select(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public struct Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

​